# how do I write this style command as a key to fix this error?

Tags: python, docx

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
table.style = 'LightShading-Accent6'
for i in range(3):
    table.rows[0].cells[i].text = table_header[i]
```

I am getting the error

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py:139: 
UserWarning: style lookup by style_id is deprecated. Use style name as key instead.
  return self._get_style_id_from_style(self[style_name], style_type)
```

Comment: That's not an error. It's a warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you have is a warning, not an error. You should still fix it of course.

The name corresponding to the style ID `LightShading-Accent6` is `Light Shading Accent 6`, so use that instead. Names are generally just the ID written out in title case with proper human-readable spacing:

```
table.style = 'Light Shading Accent 6'
```